# frame by frame animation in swiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I've enjoyed using swiftUI, but its animation engine feels limited. I have an image that I want to animate through a sequence of png images, but I can't find a default implementation of this (or a way using implicit, explicit, or transiton animations). Will I need to build a custom system that redraws the entire UI for every frame of this animation, or is there a built-in way to do this? Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `Timer` that helps to loop through an array of images and to stop the animation just `cancel` the Timer. Here transition type `.scale` is used for the demo.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let images = ["img1", "img2", "img3", "img1"]
    
    @State private var idx = 0
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var transition: AnyTransition = .scale
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                if self.idx == index {
                    Image(self.images[index])
                        .transition(transition)
                }
            }
            
        }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                self.idx = self.idx < (self.images.count - 1) ? self.idx + 1 : 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I did this in native swift storyboard but its the same concept. In SwiftUI my translation from storyboard would be similar to this:

```
var index = 0
var imageArray = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true, block:
    (timer) in {
        index++
        if (index >= imageArray.count) {
            index = 0
        }
        self.background(Image("\(imageArray[index])").resizable()
    }
)
```

This will, every 2 seconds, switch the background-image of whatever this is put into as per the array defined earlier.

Hope this fixes your issue!

Answer (score 0):

For animations, if you want **frame-by-frame** manipulatability, I would suggest you use a `CADisplayLink` which synchronizes a function call to your screen's frame-rate. It's a really powerful tool, especially for animations, hence the CA - CoreAnimation.

Although flexible, you can't use it on SwiftUI `View`'s directly, as `View` is a protocol and not a `class`, which do not allow `@objc` functions. So you will have to create a class/VM for managing the animation. A low level example is as follows

```
class ImageAnimator: ObservableObject {

    // Image to add animation/transitions
    @Published var image: Image = Image()

    private var link: CADisplayLink!

    init() {
        // Adding the link to a runloop
        link = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update))
        link.add(to: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }

    @objc func update() {
        // Do something
    }

    deinit {
        // Removes link from all runloops
        link.invalidate()
    }
}
```